# How can I deserialize a json object into a complex object?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON object into an Object with some "object" attribute that may be different each time. I have a serializer/deserializer function that works fine when using simple variable types or defined ones.

I tried to cast the object into the correct class, tried to get the object as dynamic, etc. However, I always get an exception: "Object Reference not established..."

Deserialization func:

```
        public static T deserializeJSON<T>(string json)
        {
            T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType($
                obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
            }
            return obj;
        }
```

Example object:

```
 [DataContract]
    class Client
    {
        [DataMember] private string name;
        [DataMember] private string address;
        [DataMember] private string bio;
        [DataMember] private object specific; //WHERE SPECIFIC MAY BE ANY OTHER OBJECT THAT I CAST AFTER DESERIALIZATION
    }
```

Example object2:

```
 [DataContract]
    class Server
    {
        [DataMember] private string name;
        [DataMember] private int value;
    }
```

The specific attribute may be any other object. Imagine "specific" attribute is a Server type object; The deserialization function loads all attributes well instead of specific that is loaded as an object, but cannot convert it to Server.

PD: At deserialization moment, I know what class type is the "specific" attribute.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to postpone deserializing parts of the json object hierarchy until you know more about which types are involved, you can either write a custom converter that does it on-the-fly as part of the deserialization, or instead of `object` you can use `JToken`, this is a Json.net object that you later can do `.ToObject<something>()` on to complete the deserialization, once you know what that "something" should be.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Would try it! However, could it be done without using Newtonsoft?

Comment: I have no idea, you would have to check the specific library you want to use. I don't know if DataContractJsonSerializer supports it, but [even Microsoft recommends using Json.net now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8). If your library can deserialize to dynamic by creating a property bag or whatnot, then probably.

Comment: Guess that should migrate to JSON.NET... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using latest json.net you can use

```
dynamic data = Json.Decode(json);
```

or

```
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(json);
```

and can access data with following code :

```
data.Date; 
data.Items.Count; 
data.Items[0].Name; 
data.Items[0].Price; 
data.Items[1].Name;
```